# A riddle that we all know the answer to - because we are a part of it

Tags: riddle

I'm a thing of two names. (It depends on from where you came.)

And the name of 6 games. (Played by both gentlemen and dames.)

This thing has brought our species much fame. (And in it we are all the same.)

Society rests upon me, the frame. (What's my name?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, I think it's:

> Civilization

I'm a thing of two names. (It depends on from where you came.)

> The word is spelled with either a 'z' or an 's' (US or British spelling).

And the name of 6 games. (Played by both gentleman and dames.)

> There are six computer games with the titles "Civilization" through "Civilization VI".

"This thing has brought our species much fame. (And in it we are all the same.)"

> Humans are the only "civilized" species on the planet. Not sure about "all the same", though!

"Society rests upon me, the frame. (What's my name?)"

> Modern society is certainly based on civilization.

Also:

> The title is a clue: "A riddle that we all know the answer to - because we are a part of it"
>  Every (internet-using, at least) person is a part of "civilization".

Comment: Nice, that's right!

Answer (score 4):

> The Universal Declaration of Human Rights

I'm a thing of two names. (It depends on from where you came.)

> The acronym is UDHR in English, or DUDP in French (Déclaration Universelle des Droits de la Personne).

And the name of 6 games. (Played by both gentlemen and dames.)

> The United Nations has 6 official languages: Arabic, Chinese, English, French, Russian, Spanish.

This thing has brought our species much fame. (And in it we are all the same.)

> Well, it's a famous document, certainly. And it declares the rights to which all human beings are inherently entitled.

Society rests upon me, the frame. (What's my name?)

> The Universal Declaration of Human Rights could be argued to be a large part of the basis for modern society.

Comment: Nice try, but incorrect unfortunately.

Comment: So,stopme if I'm wrong.... The UDHR has an acronym in pretty much every language, so it would be of many many many names

Comment: True. You could argue that the "official" acronyms are the 6 of the official UN languages, but that's still 6 names.

Comment: And in French it is not *Déclaration Universelle des Droits de la Personne* but *Déclaration Universelle des Droits de l'Homme* ;-) just fyi !

Answer (score 2):

> The Earth

I'm a thing of two names. (It depends on from where you came.)

> The Earth / Terra

And the name of 6 games. (Played by both gentleman and dames.)

> a game is a continent: Africa, America, Antarctica, Asia, Australia, Europe

This thing has brought our species much fame. (And in it we are all the same.)

> something related to all of us being a part of the same world maybe?

Society rests upon me, the frame. (What's my name?)

> society is built on Earth.

Comment: Close but this isn't the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a thing of two names. (It depends on from where you came.)

> Knowlege/wisdom

And the name of 6 games. (Played by both gentlemen and dames.)

> 5Ws and one H. Questions we ask to get knowledge.

This thing has brought our species much fame. (And in it we are all the same.)

> Homo sapiens

Society rests upon me, the frame. (What's my name?)

> Knowledge is the foundation of human society

Comment: An interesting thought, but that's not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first-timer here.

I'm a thing of two names. (It depends on from where you came.)

> Male/Female

And the name of 6 games. (Played by both gentlemen and dames.)

> Mother/Father, Brother/Sister, Son/Daughter

This thing has brought our species much fame. (And in it we are all the same.)

> a) The mother ("in it" = the womb), or b) sex ("in it" = love)

Society rests upon me, the frame. (What's my name?)

> Reproduction

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you can also be *other things* to your second point(I don't want spoilers, but you can surely think of something, e.g. more elderly :)), so if that's correct answer, I don't like the riddle.